# How to run .net function in ColdFusion

Tags: c#, .net, windows, coldfusion

I'm a junior C# developer and I'm trying to learn Web Development with ColdFusion. I'm having difficulty running this example in the documentation: [Using a .NET class directly](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13e1a-7fe2.html). This is just a simple cfm code to test .NET function on ColdFusion.

```
<cffunction name="Ping" returntype="string" output="false"> 
    <cfargument name="host" type="string" required="yes"> 
    <!--- Local variables ---> 
    <cfset var pingClass=""> 
    <cfset var pingReply=""> 
    <!--- Get Ping class ---> 
    <cfobject type=".NET" name="pingClass" 
            class="System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping"> 
    <!--- Perform synchronous ping (using defaults) --->  
    <cfset pingReply=pingClass.Send(Arguments.host)> 
    <!--- Return result ---> 
    <cfreturn pingReply.Get_Status().ToString()> 
</cffunction>
```

I installed ColdFusion 2016 with these settings: Server Configuration,
Production Profile + Secure Profile with IP address 127.0.0.1, .NET integration Service, and Built-in web server.

I placed the CFM code here C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\test.cfm and I ran it through the browser like this `http://127.0.0.1:8500/test.cfm`. The error that I get from jnbridge log is "Class Not Found". I have .NET framework installed and the ColdFusion .NET service is running. I also tried restarting everything but it still won't work. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Tip: You may want to take a look at [cfscript](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/extending-coldfusion-pages-with-cfml-scripting.html). As of CF11+, just about anything you can do with CFML ie tags, is also supported in cfscript. The syntax is very similar to java / C#, so you may find it more natural coming from C#.

Answer (score 4):

> Class System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping not found in the specified
>   assembly list.
>
> The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the **assembly**
>   attribute.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfobject-net-object.html

http://cfdocs.org/cfobject

This seems to work:

```
<cfobject type="dotnet" name="pingClass"
    assembly="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
    class="System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping">
```

You can also use `createObject()` instead of `<cfobject>`.
http://cfdocs.org/createobject

Comment: I still get the same error "com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ClassNotFoundException"  Henry, but thank you though. I suspect the problem is the way I installed ColdFusion on my machine or something. Do you think my settings that I described is correct though?

Comment: @jordan check your path to the mscorlib.dll, it may be different on yours depending on the .net version you have on your PC.

Comment: @jordan - For grins, try `System.dll` for the assembly. Supposedly that is where it is located [if the docs are to be believed...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx).  Though given that it is part of the core libraries, I am curious why you need to specify a path... Also, I am not sure how accurate the error messages are since I got the exact same "Class not found..." error running the original example on an instance that did not even have the .NET service installed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So my coworker figured it out how to run the code in CF. Here are the steps from the beginning

1. Install CF Server
2. Install CF Builder without creating another server
3. On the builder, add CF server by clicking + button somewhere
4. Type the name 'coldfusion' not coldfusion2016' or 'coldfusion10'. Just 'coldfusion'.
5. Run the cfm through CFBuilder

Comment: Did you post this on the right thread? :-) How did that resolve the ClassNotFound exception?

Comment: Ha! I was wondering the same thing. Seems this answer was posted to the wrong question.

Comment: Yea that's true, I didn't explain the whole process me and my coworker have been through. I just posted the final solution and it doesn't make sense to the question I posted. But I had to share this